# How to tell gradlew to use existing gradle rather than downloading it everytime?

Tags: gradle

Sorry, have no gradle experience before, play with https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

```
MINGW64 /d/workspace/gs-rest-service/complete (master)
$ ./gradlew bootRun
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
```

I already installed gradle here:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ /d/prefix/gradle-5.5/bin/gradle

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 5.5.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 599ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

How can I tell gradlew to use installed one, do not download it everytime enerywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), `gradlew`, will always download the *specific* version of Gradle configured in `<project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` if that version of Gradle has not been downloaded before (and is available at `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`). The reason is that the project is supposed to know best with which version of Gradle it should be used. If you still want to use your globally installed version of Gradle, simply add it to `PATH` and call `gradle` instead of `gradlew`.

Comment: Thank you from zero experience gradle user, now I know what w stands  for in gradlew